# How to covert a "www.google.com" coming from a stub to "https://www.google.com" in Spring MVC?

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC to design a banner. On click the image I am to redirect the user to "www.google.com".

JSP code-

```
<a href="www.google.com">
            <img alt="google.com" src="skins/sunlift/styleImages/navbar_pic/aboutus_n.jpg">
            </a>
```

The page redirection is not happening using this code. 
On adding a "http://" before "www.google.com" id doing the trick.

Modified JSP-

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img alt="google.com" src="skins/sunlift/styleImages/navbar_pic/aboutus_n.jpg">
            </a>
```

Is there a better way to format this code without explicitly stating the "https://" ?

Comment: adding http: is required , just using www.google.com means it is under your current url(current project)

Comment: ohkay....alright! Thank you :)